# Firebase Reactjs: How to get data of specific document in firebase using where clause, and then displaying the data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

For example, in my "Notification" collection, there are multiple different documents, but this is the [specific one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAnCK.jpg) that I want to get.

I want to only get and print full document that has "abc" as the "name" value, but currently having some trouble doing that.

Here's my code for getting the data from firebase:

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let list = [];
      try {
        const qu = query(collection(db, "Notification"), where("name", "==", "abc"));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(qu);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });

        setData1(list);

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

In the return section, i'm printing the data with:

```
<span className="printdata">{data1.name}</span>
```

However, the data is not printing. Am I doing something wrong here, or do I have to map the data1 before printing?

If so, how could I do it so that it displays the values that are retrieved from the firebase document?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure therer will be only 1 document returned - You need to use index to get 1st element due to data1 is an array, not an object (or rewrite your code to make data1 a more plain object, not an array):

```
return (<span className="printdata">{data1[0]?.name} </span>);
```

If there could be many documents as per data1 is an array for that reason - you need to use .map function:

```
  return (
    <>
      {data1.map((item) => (
        <span key={item.id} className="printdata">{item.name}</span>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```